# Is $lcm( lcm(n_1, n_2, ..., n_m), n_{m+1}) = lcm(n_1, n_2, ..., n_m, n_{m+1})$?

Tags: least-common-multiple

> Is $lcm( lcm(n_1, n_2, ..., n_m), n_{m+1}) = lcm(n_1, n_2, ..., n_m,
>   n_{m+1})$?

And if so, how can we prove it ?

I thought first I open $lcm(n_1, n_2, ..., n_m)$ as $n_1*a_1 + n_2*a_2 + ...  = d_n$ and then write $d_n * a'_n + n_{m+1}*a_{m+1}$, but as far as I know, I cannot conclude the result from this point of view.

Comment: Prove that they divide each other. Then they have to be equal.

Comment: How about proving $lcm(a,b,c)=lcm(lcm(a,b),c)$ and using induction

Comment: @kingW3 nice thought, but I'm still not able to show it because I don't know how can I conclude to the lcm after opening the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let lcm$(n_1,...,n_m)=a,$ lcm$(a,n_{m+1})=b,$ lcm$(n_1,...,n_{m+1})=c.$

Since $\forall i = 1,...,m,$ $n_i|a$ and $a|b,n_{m+1}|b,$ we have $\forall i,$ $n_i|b,$ so $c|b.$

Since $\forall i = 1,...,m,$ $n_i|c,$ so $a|c,$ and with $n_{m+1}|c,$ we have $b|c.$

Hence $b=c.$

Comment: How do we know that every $n_i | b$ ?

Comment: for $n_i|a$ and $a|b$

Comment: How does $a|c$ ? I mean c is lcm of $n_1$ to $n_{m+1}$ ?

Comment: for $c$ is a common multiple of $n_1,...,n_m$ and by the definition of $a$